# How do I deal with multiple files with the same name in a single Package.swift?

Tags: ios, swift

When I try to build the following...

```swift
// swift-tools-version:5.3
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "...",
    defaultLocalization: "en",
    platforms: [
        .macOS(.v10_15), .iOS(.v13), .tvOS(.v13)
    ],
    products: [
        .library(name: "...", targets: ["..."]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(
            url: "https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-ios",
            from: "0.51.2"
        ),
        .package(
            url: "https://github.com/auth0/Auth0.swift.git",
            from: "2.0.0"
        ),
        .package(
            url: "https://github.com/pkluz/PKHUD.git",
            from: "5.4.0"
        )
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "...",
            dependencies: [
                .product(name: "Apollo", package: "apollo-ios"),
                .product(name: "ApolloSQLite", package: "apollo-ios"),
                .product(name: "Auth0", package: "Auth0.swift"),
                .product(name: "PKHUD", package: "PKHUD"),
            ]
        ),
        .testTarget(
            name: "...",
            dependencies: [
                .target(name: "...")
            ]
        ),
    ]
)
```

But when I run I get...

```
'ios-...-mobile-app': error: multiple resources named 'DirectoryViewController.xib' in target '...'
error: ExitCode(rawValue: 1)
[0/1] Planning build'ios-...-mobile-app': error: multiple resources named 'DirectoryViewController.xib' in target 'pure'
```

I do see 2 controllers with the same name so how do I tell Swift to distinguish them both?

One is in...

> .../Sources/pure/UI/Controllers/CommsHub/Calls/Keypad + Directory/Directory/DirectoryViewController.xib

The other

> .../Sources/pure/UI/Controllers/CommsHub/Directory/DirectoryViewController.xib

To be clear I do not want to do this with XCode.

Answer (score 0):

Try to concrete usage of this things by:

```swift
<nameOfThePackage>.DirectoryViewController.xib
```

So it will looks like:

```swift
Apollo.DirectoryViewController.xib
```